# Display glyphicon in block immediately when radio button is checked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have the below form and am using css to display display span when radio button is clicked using the code

```
  <style>
.glyphicon{
  display: none;
}

input[type="radio"]:checked + span{
 display: block;
}
</style>

<form>
     <div class="form-group" id="myform">
            <label for="usr">Q1:Are these dates in chronological order?1492,1941,1586                    </label>
     </div>
    <div class="radio">
      <label><input type="radio" id="opt0" name="optradio0">yes<span id="sp0" class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span></label>
    </div>
    <div class="radio">
      <label><input type="radio" id="opt1" name="optradio0">no<span id="sp1" class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span></label>
    </div>
   <br/>
</form>
```

However there is a problem that the glyphicons are visible when the page is loaded. See link below

http://upscfever.com/upsc-fever/en/apti/en-apti1-chp6a.html

However when i remove the code given below the page works fine. So how can i keep the below code and still achieve the purpose.

```
   <script>
            $(document).ready(function(){  
                                        $("#header").load("http://upscfever.com/upsc-fever/header.html");
 $("#footer").load("http://upscfever.com/upsc-fever/footer.html");


            });          
        </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can inspect the glyphicon in the dev console. Find out it's identifier, and then in your css, set it's initial display to `none`.

Don't forget to be as specific as possible to future proof it.

Comment: there is no id to glyphicons

Comment: `glyphicon-ok` this is an identifier. identifier can be a class or an id.

Comment: .glyphicon-ok{
  display: none;
}

.glyphicon-remove{
  display: none;
}

Comment: this is what i did. but no effect